# How much caffeine is left in your system?

Tags: summation, exponential-function

The [half-life of caffeine in your system is 6 hours](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7361718?dopt=Abstract). If you drink 100mg of caffeine every day, what percentage is left in your system after a week?

If you drink 100mg caffeine every day for a month (30d), how long does it take for the level of caffeine in your system to drop below 1mg?

Comment: As mathematics is the process of turning coffee into theorems, that really depends on the amount of proofs that you have come up with in that duration.

Comment: @Chloe: Obviously you were drinking far too much coffee. The following may help curb your intake: http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21584315-way-test-genuineness-worlds-costliest-coffee-brown-gold-blend.

Comment: @copper.hat Lol! I actually don't like coffee, so that's why I used 'caffeine'.

Comment: Most teas have less that 100mg per cup so I just assumed :-). –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If you drink $x$ coffee after one day you get $\frac{x}{2^4}$ left in your system. The rest is writing the proper sum.

For the first question, you will have:
$$
\frac{x}{16}+\frac{x}{16^2}+...+\frac{x}{16^7}=x\frac{1}{16}\frac{1-\frac{1}{16^7}}{1-\frac{1}{16}}
$$

For the last question, you get: 
$$
\frac{x}{16}+\frac{x}{16^2}+...+\frac{x}{16^{30}}=x\frac{1}{16}\frac{1-\frac{1}{16^{30}}}{1-\frac{1}{16}}=y
$$
You want to find $d$ such that:
$$
\frac{y}{16^d}\leq \frac{x}{100}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but the first part is incorrect. I assume you are using 'x' for the quantity instead of the # of days, but still, the end result, 16^8, is an enormous sum.

Comment: Just a typo....

Comment: by the way, in your case $x$ is 100 mg.

Comment: Ok, I believe you have made a fraction addition mistake on your first part. That is x * (.99 / .93) = 1.06 * x. So you are saying  after only one week, you have accumulated MORE caffeine in your system than the full amount of one day? Yes it is cumulative but not to that degree.

Comment: The first equation needs to have $x$ subtracted, since $1+r+...+r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$, and so $r+...+r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-1 = r \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$.

Comment: You are right... That's an embarrassment. I need some coffee...

Comment: Minor point; the first answer shows how much caffeine remains, but the question was what percentage was left after a week. The percentage should not depend on the daily dose. Also, in all cases, you are presuming that the caffeine is ingested at the very start of the day (midnight), which is unlikely :-).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both depends on when (and how, since one rarely drinks the coffee instantaneously) the coffee is consumed during the day.

For the purposes of this problem, however, I will assume that all the coffee is consumed at exactly $t_{\text{coffee}}$ every day and that we are looking for the quantity remaining at the end of the $7$th day.

At the end of a day, the contribution from that day is $100 ( \frac{1}{2} )^{ \frac{24-t_{\text{coffee}}}{6}}$, after $n$ days, this contribution  decreases to 
$100 ( \frac{1}{2} )^{ \frac{24-t_{\text{coffee}}}{6}} ( \frac{1}{2^{4} } )^n$ (since $4 = \frac{24}{6}$). Summing up, and dividing by $700$ to get the ratio gives:
$$\frac{100}{700}  (\frac{1}{2} )^{ \frac{24-t_{\text{coffee}}}{6}} 
\left( ( \frac{1}{2^{4} } )^6 + ... + ( \frac{1}{2^{4} } )^1 + 1\right)  = 
\frac{1}{7}  (\frac{1}{2} )^{ \frac{24-t_{\text{coffee}}}{6}} 
\left( \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2^{4}})^7 }{1-\frac{1}{2^{4} }} \right)$$
So, doing the computation shows that the percentage left varies between $0.95 \% -15.24 \%$ (taking $t_{\text{coffee}} \in [0,24)$). Note that this is the percentage of the total caffeine consumed during the week, which is a bit misleading, since if you took the average over $n$ days, and let $n \to \infty$, then the percentage would decrease to zero.

The other computation follows similar lines (but is less misleading):

I am assuming that you drink coffee every day for 30 days and then go cold turkey.

Then you want to find the minimum $n$ (whole days) such that
$$100  (\frac{1}{2} )^{ \frac{24-t_{\text{coffee}}}{6}} 
\left( ( \frac{1}{2^{4} } )^{29} + ... + ( \frac{1}{2^{4} } )^1 + 1\right) (\frac{1}{2^4} )^{ n}  \le 1$$
A quick calculation shows that the answer is $n=1$ or $n=2$ (depending on $t_{\text{coffee}}$).

Comment: I'm sorry, but both would appear incorrect. Why are you dividing by 700? For one day, you can do it in your head and see that 6.25% is left in your system (100% > 50% > 12.5% > 6.25%). That is 6.25mg, which shows your 2nd part is incorrect as well.

Comment: You asked what percentage is left. The total weekly intake is 700mg, hence the 700. Even if you consume the entire 700mg at say 8am, the percentage left by midnight is about 16%. And you are right for the second part (I have edited my response), it should be $n=1$ or $n=2$ depending on when you take the drink.